# LDAP group membership inheritance for nested groups

Tags: inheritance, ldap, openldap, active-directory-group

I'm working with groups in OpenLDAP to apply nested or sub-group memberships using `rfc2307bis.schema` to supersede `nis.schema`, so objectClass `groupOfNames` is being used for groups. Group membership inheritance is what I'm trying to accomplish.

For example - Let's say `engineers` is the primary group and `developers` is the secondary group. The primary `engineers` group is a **member** of the `developers` group like so:

### Secondary Group

```
dn: cn=developers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: developers
gidNumber: 9004
member: cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
description: The Secondary Group
```

The primary group looks like this:

#### Primary Group

```
dn: cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: posixGroup
member: uid=sam,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
cn: engineers
gidNumber: 9000
description: The Primary Group
```

When running `getent group developers` members of `engineers` do not show up as members of `developers`. Additionally running `id sam` only shows Sam as a member of the primary `engineers` group, but Sam should also inherit group membership of `developers` since the `developers` record contains `engineers` as a member and Sam is a member of `engineers`.

I'm testing by using a file with permissions `040` like so:

```
----r----- 1 root developers 28 Dec  4 01:49 /tmp/testfile
```

The `developers` group has 1 member in it's group record:

```
member: cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

If `/tmp/testfile` is owned by `engineers` I can read the file, but if it is owned by `developers` I cannot read the file even though `engineers` is a member of `developers`.

I then began reading about the dynlist overlay and loaded `dyngroup.schema` thinking maybe using ACLs would accomplish the overall goal of group inheritance, but I don't fully understand how to execute this if it really is Dynamic Groups I am looking for. Here is an example I thought would work.

```
dn: cn=dynamic,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfURLs
cn: dynamic
memberURL: ldap:///cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com?member?sub (objectClass=groupOfNames)
```

How can the LDAP `developers` group have file permissions to files they don't directly own but are a member of the primary group that does own `testfile`?

Comment: The dynlist OpenLDAP overlay "expands" group-like attributes of an entry if that entry has a particular objectClass. The [man page for `slapo-dynlist`](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-dynlist) says: "No recursion is allowed, to avoid potential infinite loops.". So dynlist does just one level of expansion.

Comment: OpenLDAP won't expand nested groups by itself. You need a chunk of application code to do that.

Comment: I tested this but did not get the expected result. While dynlist overlay did expand member's by their uid in my case - it looks like this made no change in the way file permissions were treated. I think if it could expand the full DN of users in ou=People it might work, but as the man page said "No recursion is allowed". Thank you rlandster